# Is $F ↾ a$ a set?

Tags: set-theory

If $F$ is a class function and $a$ is a set, is $F ↾ a$ a set?

Note: It appears in [Transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction)

Comment: It seems that $G ↾ a$ does *not* occur in the linked article. Instead, I see things like $G(F ↾ \alpha)$

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it.

Comment: OK, $F$ in the article is ultimately also a class function, not only the original $G$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use the Axiom Schema of Replacement. You may view it as 
$$F ↾ a =\{\,\langle x,Fx\rangle \mid x\in a\,\}$$

Comment: With Replacement I can have the image b after I can take $a \times b$ and separate (x,y) in axb asking that (x,y) in in F. Is it correct?

Comment: @asv Hagen combines these two steps. He considers the class function $G(x) = \langle x, F(x) \rangle$. But your approach also works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one of the axioms of set theory actually(assuming that by a class function is meant a definable function.).